# Timer queues in windows

Tags: c, windows, winapi, timer

I'm trying to use `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` to control polling of a serial port in C. I have little experience with the windows API and thus am starting with using a basic example from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003(v=vs.85).aspx). For some reason, `WAITORTIMERCALLBACK` is not recognized (undeclared) even though `windows.h` and `winbase.h` are included and all the API calls (`CreateTimerQueue()`, etc) are recognized.

The relevant code is as follows

header:

```
//serial.h

....

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#endif

....
```

and the source file:

```
//serial.c

VOID CALLBACK port_polling_win(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    //stuff will happen here
}

int create_polling_thread(serial_port *comport)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    HANDLE gDoneEvent;
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    HANDLE hTimerQueue = NULL;
    int arg = 123;

    // Use an event object to track the TimerRoutine execution
    gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (NULL == gDoneEvent)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create the timer queue.
    hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
    if (NULL == hTimerQueue)
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    // Set a timer to call the timer routine in TIMER_RESOLUTION_MS miliseconds
    if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer(&hTimer, hTimerQueue, (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK) port_polling_win, &arg, TIMER_RESOLUTION_MS, 0, 0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 3;
    }
#else
    ....
#endif
return 0;
}
```

I tried declaring `port_polling_win()` as `VOID WAITORTIMERCALLBACK`, `WAITORTIMERCALLBACK` and `void WAITORTIMERCALLBACK` so the cast in `CreateTimerQueueTimer()` wouldn't be necessary but to no avail. `WAITORTIMERCALLBACK` isn't recognized anywhere.

FYI, I'm building with MinGW GCC on a 64-bit Win7.

EDIT: If anything, the isolated example doesn't work either:

```
/*
 * main.c
 */

#include <windows.h>
#include <winbase.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE gDoneEvent;

VOID CALLBACK TimerRoutine(PVOID lpParam, BOOLEAN TimerOrWaitFired)
{
    if (lpParam == NULL)
    {
        printf("TimerRoutine lpParam is NULL\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // lpParam points to the argument; in this case it is an int

        printf("Timer routine called. Parameter is %d.\n",
                *(int*)lpParam);
        if(TimerOrWaitFired)
        {
            printf("The wait timed out.\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("The wait event was signaled.\n");
        }
    }

    SetEvent(gDoneEvent);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    HANDLE hTimerQueue = NULL;
    int arg = 123;

    // Use an event object to track the TimerRoutine execution
    gDoneEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    if (NULL == gDoneEvent)
    {
        printf("CreateEvent failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Create the timer queue.
    hTimerQueue = CreateTimerQueue();
    if (NULL == hTimerQueue)
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 2;
    }

    // Set a timer to call the timer routine in 10 seconds.
    if (!CreateTimerQueueTimer( &hTimer, hTimerQueue,
            (WAITORTIMERCALLBACK)TimerRoutine, &arg , 10000, 0, 0))
    {
        printf("CreateTimerQueueTimer failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());
        return 3;
    }

    // TODO: Do other useful work here

    printf("Call timer routine in 10 seconds...\n");

    // Wait for the timer-queue thread to complete using an event
    // object. The thread will signal the event at that time.

    if (WaitForSingleObject(gDoneEvent, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    CloseHandle(gDoneEvent);

    // Delete all timers in the timer queue.
    if (!DeleteTimerQueue(hTimerQueue))
        printf("DeleteTimerQueue failed (%d)\n", GetLastError());

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT2:
I found that `WAITORTIMERCALLBACK` is typedef'ed in `winbase.h` if `_WIN32_WINNT >= 0X0500`. Adding a `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500` after all the `#include`s to the preamble of my isolated example didn't change a thing though.

Comment: If you need a cast, you're Doing It Wrong™. If the code doesn't compile when you remove the cast, your function signature is wrong. If it does, all is well.

Comment: The cast appears in the example on MSDN I linked though.

Anyway, that's irrelevant. The problem is that WAITORTIMERCALLBACK is not recognized even though windows.h and winbase.h are successfully included.

Comment: ^^ what @IInspectable says.  It's a function pointer, so remove the cast and see what happens.  Also, maybe need stdcall instead of cdecl?  Not sure.

Comment: Ok, removing the cast suddenly lights up all the winAPI system calls as unrecognised even though `#include <windows.h>` and `#include <winbase.h>` work just fine. This might just be a problem with my build setup.

Comment: Adding it after the includes doesn't work. You need to define `_WIN32_WINNT` **before** including `windows.h`.

Comment: Do you need to include `Threadpoolapilegacyset.h` perhaps?

Comment: Phew, it's getting late here, of course the `#define _WIN32_WINNT` needs to be before the includes. Anyway, that doesn't change a thing.

Comment: Actually, it did change things! Defining `_WIN32_WINNT` and removing the cast solved the problem!

Time to stop working and go home! Thanks guys!